# How to select random option from dropdown in cypress

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, cypress

I am trying to choose a random option from a dropdown list.
No answers i found so far helped.
I have no issues selecting a specific option, since all values have IDs set.

This is simple/straightforward and its working:

```
const log = new loginPage()
            log.visit()
            log.loginEmail('test')
            log.loginPassword('test')
            log.submit()
            cy.get('#link-new-application').click()
            cy.get('#control-nationality').click()
            cy.get('#option-nationality-DZA').click()
```

Any advice for random selection? I am a beginner so any help would be much appreciated.

This is HTML:
[image]

Comment: Please show the HTML for the dropdown (from `#control-nationality` down) - is it a `<select>`  or `<div>` and how many options are there to select from?

Comment: Added the HTML, many thnaks :)

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to get all your options then click one randomly

```js
cy.get('#control-nationality').click()  // open the dropdown

cy.get('id^="option-nationality-"]')    // all elements with id starting "option-nationality"
  .then($options => {
    const count = $options.length
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * count)
    const randomOption = $options.eq(randomIndex) 
    cy.wrap(randomOption).click()
  })
```

Comment: Ok, this is something I understand, will try it asap. Very grateful for your help :)))

Comment: Just another quick question, i tried this, I only have issues with last click () - which has a strikethrough, I also tried .trigger, however it does not work. While running the test is seems it stops straight after the dropdown is opened.

Comment: Added `cy.wrap()` to remove the `strikethrough` Gia13 is talking about, although it's an editor artifact and the code works in the original form too.

Answer (score 1):

Cypress comes with Lodash baked in.

Lodesh brings a lot handy utility methods, with the `sample` method you can get a random item from a collection.

https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/_#Syntax

https://lodash.com/docs#sample

```js
cy.get('id^="option-nationality-"]')
  .then(options => {
    cy.get(Cypress._.sample(options)).click()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The Lodash example given by tlolkema has some mistakes.

The `options` parameter is an object, not an array. It has a numbered property for each option, but it also has these properties

- `length`
- `prevObject`
- `selector`

The Lodash `sample()` method can work on an object, but it returns one of the object's properties.

So sometimes `Cypress._.sample(options)` will return one of the three properties listed above, and your test will fail for unexpected reason.

The correct way to do it is by converting the `options` to an array first.

You would also `cy.wrap()` the selected option, not `cy.get()` it.

```js
cy.get('id^="option-nationality-"]')
  .then(options => {
    const sample = Cypress._.sample(options.toArray())
    cy.wrap(sample).click()
})
```